# C# Print pdf file programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, printdocument

My printing code given below

```
void SaveReport(Telerik.Reporting.Report report, string fileName)
{
    ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
    instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = report;
    RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
    }

    // initialize PrintDocument object
    PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument()
    {
        PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings()
        {
            // set the printer to 'Microsoft Print to PDF'
            PrinterName = "Canon LBP3000",

            // tell the object this document will print to file
            // PrintToFile = true,

            // set the filename to whatever you like (full path)
            PrintFileName = fileName,
        }
    };
    doc.DocumentName = "My";
    doc.Print();
}
```

Then I call the function like

```
SaveReport(new ThermalPrint(), Server.MapPath(@"~\Report\123.pdf"));
```

The function executes without error but printer not print the pdf file.
The printer printing dialog like 
[image]

I can't understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the report, call [`reportProcessor.PrintReport(typeReportSource, printerSettings)`](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/m-telerik-reporting-processing-reportprocessor-printreport) but make sure you provide a valid   [`PrinterSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) instance.